# Getting id of item in list<object> in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I don't have any idea what approach and how I should start coding to get the `id` of a specific object item when a form button is clicked.

[image]

The **Product Id** values showing are **primary keys** of the product table I created. I'm coming from Swing programming and in **Swing** I can easily use the `JLabel.getText();` to get the product Ids `1,4,5,6` shown on the screenshot. But I guess it's different with **JSF**.

Also, these object values are contained in a `ui:repeat` loop

**frames.xhtml**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{frameBean.all}" var="f" varStatus="loop">
            <h:outputText escape="false" rendered="#{loop.index % 3 == 0}" />
            <div >
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
                        <img src="..." alt="frame image placeholder" width="240" height="180"/>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>
                                    <h:outputLabel>Product ID: </h:outputLabel>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{f.product_id}"/>
                                </p>
                                <p><h:outputLabel value="#{f.name}"/></p>
                                <p><h:outputText value="#{f.description}"/></p>
                                <p>
                                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{login.userRole eq 'customer' or login.userRole eq null}">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Add To Cart</a> 
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h:outputText escape="false" rendered="#{loop.last or (loop.index + 1) % 3 == 0}" />
        </ui:repeat>
```

Surely, I can use the `f.product_Id` but how can I get a specific Id if **Add To Cart** button is clicked?

Here's the implementation containing the `getAll()` frames method

```
public List<Frame> getAll() throws SQLException {
        List<Frame> list = new ArrayList<>();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            String SQL = "select product_id, name, description, price_per_sqft, material from product where isFrame = 1";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);

            //get customer data from database
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                Frame frame = new Frame();

                frame.setProduct_id(result.getInt("product_id"));
                frame.setName(result.getString("name"));
                frame.setDescription(result.getString("description"));
                frame.setPrice_per_sqft(result.getDouble("price_per_sqft"));
                frame.setMaterial(result.getString("material"));

                //store all data into a List
                list.add(frame);
            }
        } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                ps.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

For the purpose of obtaining the product Id of the frame I'm thinking of creating an `addToCart(int aProductId)` method. It will require `aProductId` argument.

Thank you.

Comment: Offtopic: Don't do any work in getters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use f:param component for store the product id

```
<p>
    <h:outputLabel>Product ID: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputText value="#{f.product_id}"/>
    <f:param name="productId" value=""#{f.product_id}""></f:param>
</p>
```

and later in the bean you can get the value by using FacesContext

```
String propertyId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                .get("productId");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the `var` attribute of the `ui:repeat`. Code a method in the backing bean `addToCart(Frame f)`.

```
public void addToCart(Frame pFrameAdded){
    //Do your operations over the frame added. 
}
```

This method needs to be called from your xhtml when a click action is performed.
Something like this:-
    `<a href="#{frameBean.addToCart(f)}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Add To Cart</a>`

Here the parameter passed to the method is the `var` attribute of the `ui:repeat`which is used to uniquely identify each element of the list of elements passed to `ui:repeat`.

Hope this solves your problem.