# How to get RowIndex from the actual selected Column into my Bean?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I try to get the rowindex from the actual selected Column to unselect it with:

```
 public void rowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        MyDataView selected = (MyDataView) event.getObject();
        if (!selectedData.remove(selected)) {
            selectedData.add(selected);
        } else {      
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('datatTable').unselectRow(rowindex);");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is easy to unselect a row with the UnselectEvent and press "crtl" but my Customers want to unselect a row with one click.

```
    <p:dataTable widgetVar="datatTable" id="idDataTable" value="#{bean.dataview}" var="data" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"
                             rowSelectMode="add" selectionMode="multiple"
                selection="#{sendGroupSmsSimple.selectedReceivers}" rowKey="#{bean.id}" filteredValue="#{data.filterData}" rowIndexVar="dataRowIndex">
        <p:column id="recColumn" headerText="Name" filterBy="#{bean.fullname}" filterFunction="#{data.filterData}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.fullname}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{sendGroupSmsSimple.rowSelect}" process="@this" update="mainForm:updatePanel"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

I don't want to update my whole Form because I want the actual state of my scrollbar.
My actual Primefaces Version is 6.0.
Scope of my Bean is GroupedConversationScoped.
Thanks

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836203/getting-id-of-item-in-listobject-in-jsf/40836517#40836517

Comment: Why not determine that client-side in the oncomplete of the ajax call?